# How to flip the UIView which is inside Tableview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want flip UIView which is inside tableview if older data is not matched with new data.The UIView is flipping but the issue is when getting more table row then UIView continously flipping.

**Struct**

```
struct SMatchOddsData{
    
    var mktId:String
    var runnerName:String
    var back: Double
    var lay: Double
    init(mktId: String, runnerName:String, back: Double, lay: Double) {
        self.mktId = mktId
        self.runnerName = runnerName
        self.back = back
        self.lay = lay
    }
    
}

class smtchOddsData {
    
    var mtchoddsdatas:[SMatchOddsData] = []
    public static let sharedInstance = smtchOddsData()
    
    private init() {
        self.mtchoddsdatas = []
    }
    
    public func add(mktId: String, runnerName:String, back: Double, lay: Double) throws {
        
        mtchoddsdatas.append(SoccerMatchOddsData(mktId: mktId, runnerName:runnerName, back: back, lay: lay))
    }
    
    public func ReplaceAtIndex(Index:Int, mktId: String, runnerName:String, back: Double, lay: Double) throws {
        mtchoddsdatas[Index] = SoccerMatchOddsData(mktId: mktId, runnerName:runnerName, back: back, lay: lay)
    }
    
}
```

**Array and Timer**

```
var timer = Timer()
var mainArray = smtchOddsData.sharedInstance
```

**In viewDidLoad**

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(LiveViewController.refreshData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

**MarketList Function**

In this api getting market id

```
func MarketList()
    {
        let params = [String : AnyObject]()
        
        APIClient<MarketList>().API_GET(Url: strUrl, Params: params, Authentication: false, Progress: false, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (resultdata) in
            
            for response in resultdata
            {
               self.OddsInplay(marketId: response.marketID)
            }
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**OddInplay Function**

In this function im getting all data which I want to display in tableview.

```
func OddsInplay(marketId:String)
    {
        let params = [String : AnyObject]()
        
        APIClient<OddInplay>().API_GET(Url: strUrl, Params: params, Authentication: false, Progress: false, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (resultdata) in
            
            self.mainArray.mtchoddsdatas.removeAll()
            for i in resultdata.first?.runners ?? []
            {
                try? self.mainArray.add(mktId: marketId, runnerName: i.runnerName ?? "", back: i.exchangePrices?.availableToBack?.first?.price ?? 0.0, lay: i.exchangePrices?.availableToLay?.first?.price ?? 0.0)
            }
            self.isStarted1 = self.isStarted1 + 1
           
            self.ReplaceOddsInplay(marketId:marketId)
            self.marketTableView.reloadData()
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**ReplaceOddInplay Function**

In this function im replacing old data with new data

```
func ReplaceOddsInplay(marketId:String)
    {
        let params = [String : AnyObject]()
        
        APIClient<OddInplay>().API_GET(Url: strUrl, Params: params, Authentication: false, Progress: false, Alert: true, Offline: false, SuperVC: self, completionSuccess: { (resultdata) in
  
            for i in resultdata.first?.runners ?? []
            {
                var isMatched = false
                var index = 0
                
                for j in self.mainArray.mtchoddsdatas
                {
                    if j.runnerName == i.runnerName
                    {
                        isMatched = true
                        break;
                    }
                    index = index + 1;
                }
                
                if isMatched == true {
                    
                    try? self.mainArray.ReplaceAtIndex(Index: index, mktId: marketId, runnerName: i.runnerName ?? "", back: i.exchangePrices?.availableToBack?[0].price ?? 0.0, lay: i.exchangePrices?.availableToLay?[0].price ?? 0.0)
                    
                }
            }
            
        })
        { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

**TableView**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return mainArray.mtchoddsdatas.count
    
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "matchOddsCell", for: indexPath) as! SoccerMatchOddTableViewCell
                
            let obj = mainArray.mtchoddsdatas[indexPath.row]
               
                
            cell.runnerName.text = obj.runnerName
                
            let newback = String(obj.back)
                   
                if newback == "0.0"
                {
                    cell.backLabel.text = "-"
                }
                else
                {
                    if isStarted1 > 1 && (cell.backLabel.text ?? "" != newback)
                    {
                        UIView.transition(with: cell.backView, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft], animations: nil, completion: nil)
                    }
                    cell.backLabel.text = newback
                }
                
                let newlay = String(obj.lay)
                        
                if newlay == "0.0"
                {
                    cell.layLabel.text = "-"
                }
                else
                {
                    if isStarted1 > 1 && (cell.layLabel.text ?? "" != newlay)
                    {
                        UIView.transition(with: cell.layView, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft], animations: nil, completion: nil)
                    }
                    cell.layLabel.text = "\(newlay)"
                }
           
            return cell
        }
```

I want to flip UIView only if old data is not equal to new data.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Comment: yes I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so my theory is:

`cell.layLabel.text ?? ""` will always return `""` when you call `reloadData()`. Hence it will always be different than newBack/ newLay.

What you need to do is keep track of your oldLay/ oldBack and check those instead of `cell.layLabel.text`. Either in an array in the class or new variables in your model.

Try this:

1. Add 2 variables to your class: `var oldLays = [String]()` & `var oldBacks = [String]()`.
2. Replace your `cellForRow` with:

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "matchOddsCell", for: indexPath) as! SoccerMatchOddTableViewCell
        let oldLay = oldLays.count > indexPath.row ? oldLays[indexPath.row]: ""
         let oldBack = oldBacks.count > indexPath.row ? oldBacks[indexPath.row]: ""
        let obj = mainArray.mtchoddsdatas[indexPath.row]


        cell.runnerName.text = obj.runnerName

        let newback = String(obj.back)

        if newback == "0.0"
        {
            cell.backLabel.text = "-"
        }
        else
        {
            if isStarted1 > 1 && (oldBack != newback)
            {
                UIView.transition(with: cell.backView, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft], animations: nil, completion: nil)
            }
            cell.backLabel.text = newback
        }

        let newlay = String(obj.lay)
        if newlay == "0.0"
        {
            cell.layLabel.text = "-"
        }
        else
        {
            if isStarted1 > 1 && (oldLay != newlay)
            {
                UIView.transition(with: cell.layView, duration: 1.0, options: [.transitionFlipFromLeft], animations: nil, completion: nil)
            }
            cell.layLabel.text = "\(newlay)"
        }
        if oldLays.count <= indexPath.row {
            oldLays.append("\(obj.lay)")
        }else {
           oldLays[indexPath.row] = "\(obj.lay)"
        }
        if oldBacks.count <= indexpath.row {
            oldBacks.append("\(obj.back)")
        }else {
            oldBacks[indexPath.row] = "\(obj.back)"
        }
        return cell
    }
   ```

Comment: Actually I didn't getting what you trying explain me

Comment: When you reload the table view the label will be empty, so it will always be different than whatever value you're comparing it to.

Comment: okay than what should I do can you show me how to do

Comment: its getting crash

Comment: where do you assign the value to the variable @NoeOnJupeter

Comment: At the end of the func before return cell

Comment: if oldLays.isEmpty { //
         oldLays.append(obj.lay) //
     }else { //
         oldLays[indexPath.row] = obj.lay //
     } //
     if oldBacks.isEmpty { //
         oldBacks.append(obj.lay) //
     }else { //
         oldBacks[indexPath.row] = obj.back //
     } //   This one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245218/discussion-between-noeonjupiter-and-aryan-vishwakarma).